# Android: JSONParser returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I've read many other topics on SO from people who received the same exception, but none of the proposed solutions worked. So here's my problem:

I'm trying to download a userlist from my database through a function in my app. The JSONParser keeps returning a NullPointException on this particular table from the database. I've successfully used the JSONParser class on other queries, but it doesn't work on this one. I've tested the PHP file which handles the query, and it returns the exact values I want as a JSON OBject. If the table is empty, it returns:

```
{
    "success":0,
    "message":"No users found"
}
```

If the table contains user information, it returns:

```
{
    "success":1,
    "users":[
        {    
            "ID":someID1,
            "NAME":someName1
            "PHONE":somePhoneNumber1
        },
        {    
            "ID":someID2,
            "NAME":someName2 
            "PHONE":somePhoneNumber2
        }]
}
```

I'm starting the request by calling

```
LoadAllUsers load = new LoadAllUsers();
load.execute();
```

in a certain method. This is my LoadAllUsers class:

```js
public class LoadAllUsers extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(allUsers.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Laden van alle gebruikers...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... args) {
        updateJSONData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        updateList();
    }
}
```

I receive a NullPointerException on the first line of my updateJSONdata() method, which is:

```
public void updateJSONData() {
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(my_url);
    try {
        int success = json.getInt("success");
        if (success == 1) {
            JSONArray users = json.getJSONArray("users");
            for (int i = 0; i<users.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString("ID");
                String name = c.getString("NAAM");
                String phone =c.getString("TELEFOON");
                HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("ID",id);
                map.put("name",name);
                map.put("phonenumber",phone);
                if (phoneNumber == phone) {
                    ID = Integer.parseInt(id);
                    this.name = name;
                }
                userlist.add(map);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("Geen succes!", "Helaas!");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So, the exception is thrown in the line with jParser.getJSONFromUrl(...).
My JSONParser class, of which jParser is an instance, is:

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // Extract data from the response.
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // Open an inputStream with the data content.
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        String line = null;

        // Build the string until null.
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        // Close the input stream.
        is.close();
        // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return the JSON Object.
    return jObj;

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            Log.d("Gemaakte paramstring",paramString);
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            Log.d("httpResponse: ",httpResponse.toString());
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

}

And the LogCat message is:

```js
05-07 10:46:24.995  27615-27686/com.example.user.my_app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.user.my_app, PID: 27615
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.user.my_appcenter_tile.updateJSONData(center_tile.java:376)
        at com.example.user.my_app.center_tile$Memberlist.doInBackground(center_tile.java:419)
        at com.example.user.my_app.center_tile$Memberlist.doInBackground(center_tile.java:406)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me out with this problem.

Comment: What line is `center_tile.java:376`?

Comment: That's the first line of my updateJSONdata() method:

    `JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(my_url);`

Comment: Well then `jParser` is null.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I don't understand why. My php script returns a proper json encoded object.

Comment: You did not post code regarding what `jParser` is nor how it's created...

Comment: That's quite a hint right there. Thank you, I found the error...

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer then, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `jParser` is null in `updateJSONdata()`.

Make sure to check if it's `!= null` before using it.

And if it should not be null, then fix your code.

Your error is just a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Maybe use `JSONObject json = new JSONParser().getJSONFromUrl(my_url)`?

Comment: That did the job, indeed. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'has' keyword to check availability of json keys, then can parse Json to avoid exception,otherwise you can track via Null Pointer exception.

```
    public void updateJSONData() {
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(my_url);
        try {
            int success = json.getInt("success");
            boolean isAvail=json.has("users");
            if (success == 1) {
                if(isAvail)
                JSONArray users = json.getJSONArray("users");
                for (int i = 0; i<users.length(); i++) {
                   }
                }
             }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still produces a `NullPointerException` because `jParser` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** jParser is NULL so use

```
// make sure my_url has json string in it
// read json first and use in place of my_url
JSONObject jsonObjTokener = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(my_url).nextValue();
// get success
String isSuccess = jsonObjTokener.getString("success");
// get users
JSONObject mUser = jsonObjTokener.getJSONObject("users");
```

at that line

**2.** You did spelling mistake at

```
String name = c.getString("NAAM");
```

correct to

```
String name = c.getString("NAME");
```